# Como realizar el Binding a un ComboBox en Windows Forms

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, binding

Necesito hacer binding a un `Combobox` para guardar automáticamente los datos en la BD.

*Lleno el `Combobox` al iniciar el `Form`:

```
lPropositosInmueble = BOPropositoInmueble.PropositoInmuebleCollection
    With Me.cboProposito
        .DisplayMember = "Nombre"
        .ValueMember = "PropositoID"
        .DataSource = lPropositosInmueble
        .SelectedIndex = -1
    End With
```

Al buscar el dato de la tabla hago que coincida con el `Combobox` y aplico el binding:

```
bindingPropositoiImueble = New Binding("SelectedValue", lPropositosInmueble, "Nombre", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, Nothing)
    Me.cboProposito.DataBindings.Add(bindingPropositoiImueble)
    Me.cboProposito.SelectedValue = captacion.PropositoInmuebleID
```

Para guardar:

```
If captacion.IsDirty = False Then
   captacion.Update()
End If
```

`captacion` es un objeto (tabla) ya instanciado y que sí está guardando los otros datos de los `Textbox` de ésta forma:

```
Me.txtPrecioCLP.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", captacion, "Precio", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, Nothing, "C0"))
```

El problema es que no me guarda lo seleccionado en los `Combobox` cuando quiero hacer un cambio, para los `Textbox` hago lo mismo y sí me funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que noto es que si bien defines el `Binding` tambien estas asignando el `SelectedValue` desde codigo.

Deberias quitar esta linea

```
 Me.cboProposito.SelectedValue = captacion.PropositoInmuebleID
```

Y en el binding definir la propiedad

```
bindingPropositoiImueble = New Binding("SelectedValue", captacion, "PropositoInmuebleID", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, Nothing)
```

No se porque habias puesto "Nombre" si alli va al propiedad que se bindea al SelectedValue. Se deberia asociar el campo que represente el `ValueMember`.

Tambien analiza como en el binding debes asignar el objeto `captacion` que usaste con TextBox.

En resumen en objeto `lPropositosInmueble` es correcto usarlo para cargar los items del combo, pero para determinar el binding cual define la seleccion debes usar `captacion`.

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfecto! Gracias una vez más Leandro.